# Sending jQuery Ajax request to a url in subdomain

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to send a jquery ajax request to process login to a php file which is in a subdomain but Im getting `500: internal server error`. The main site is example.com while the subdomain is subsite. Below is the code:

```
var formData = {'username':username, 'password':password};

$.ajax({
   type: 'POST',
   url: 'http://www.example.com/subsite/controllers/processLogin.php',
   data: formData,
   dataType: 'json',
   encode: true
});
```

Can someone please point out to me where I'm getting it wrong?

Comment: It looks like your request is correct. Usually `500: Internal Server Error` are, well, internal, meaning the `processLogin.php` script is throwing an error. Posting that might help us debug it.

Comment: Are you using some php framework? Im asking because of the controller.

Comment: No, I am not using any framework. Controller is just a folder.

Comment: If I change the code in processLogin to the one below, the request is successfull but I dont receive any response: if (@$_POST['clicked'] == "login") {
  //$class = new ProcessLogin();
  //$login = $class->authenticate();
  $login = "Hi There";
  echo json_encode($login);
 }

Comment: No response is likely because `$login` is not an array. Try `$login = array('Hi There');` instead.

Answer (score 1):

`500 Internal Server Error` is coming from your backend, therefor JS code wont be of much help here.

You should look into your web server logs. Depending on your server stack and configuration they could be situated at: `/var/log/apache2/error.log` (apache) `/var/log/nginx/nginx_error.log(nginx)`.

After you found the error message you will probably be able to debug this yourself, if not you can repost here with the proper informations.